# Facebook like button title on page

Tags: php, javascript, facebook, fbml

Hello
I have a like button set up on my app. The link to one of the pages in the app is

> `http://apps.facebook.com/heyulike/post3.php?id=4`

If you click on the like button and then check your profile, you will see something like :

> Name likes Cool Pos on heyulike

Everything is fine about this except in my php code, after Cool Pos in the title i have the actual post as well. In this case the post is called **something** . Hence the correct way this should display on my profile should be

> Name likes Cool Pos something on heyulike

But for some reason this string is always being omitted from the title tag or rather it is there in the title tag but fb is not displaying it. 
I confirmed that it does infact appear in the title tag by going to the main url i.e.

> `http://www.conceptscentral.com/ulike/post3.php?id=4`

If you view source and check the title tag you will see it says Cool Pos something

How can i fix this?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think you missed to add `<head>` and `<body>` tags. The `<title>` tag must be inside the `<head>` tag.